# Morphia mapping Generics

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, morphia

To simulate the behavior I see I wrote this test (gives the same exact error):

```java
@Test
public void testListGenerics() {

    @Entity
    class BaseOne<T> {
        @Id
        ObjectId _id;
        T value;
        void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    class ListBase<ITEM> extends BaseOne<List<ITEM>> { }

    class ConcreteOne extends ListBase<String> {}

    ConcreteOne concreteOne = new ConcreteOne();
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello, ", "world");
    concreteOne.setValue(strings);
    morphia.toDBObject(concreteOne);

}
```

When trying to map this I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.google.code.morphia.utils.ReflectionUtils.getParameterizedClass(ReflectionUtils.java:306)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.utils.ReflectionUtils.getParameterizedClass(ReflectionUtils.java:302)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.utils.ReflectionUtils.getParameterizedClass(ReflectionUtils.java:324)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.utils.ReflectionUtils.getParameterizedClass(ReflectionUtils.java:302)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.utils.ReflectionUtils.getParameterizedType(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappedField.discoverMultivalued(MappedField.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappedField.discover(MappedField.java:96)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappedField.(MappedField.java:76)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappedClass.discover(MappedClass.java:197)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappedClass.(MappedClass.java:119)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.getMappedClass(Mapper.java:225)
>     at
>   com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.getWriteConcern(DatastoreImpl.java:1346)
>     at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:934)

What can I do to make this work ?

Comment: Which version of Morphia do you use?

Comment: What version of Morphia you are using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.104

Answer (score 0):

You should file an issue on github and i'll take a deeper look.